# KeyPress on input not worked

Tags: javascript, binding, kendo-ui, observable

I need create keyPress (enter) binding for input.

```
<div id="body">
    <input type="text" data-value-update="keyup" data-bind="value: text, keyPress: onKeyPress"/>
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.keyPress = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function (element, bindings, options) {
        kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);
        var binding = this.bindings.keyPress;
        $(element.input).bind("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                binding.get();
            }
        });
    },
    refresh: function () { }
});

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    text: '',
    onKeyPress: function () {
        $("#output").append("<div>keyPress</div>");
    }
});

kendo.bind("#body", viewModel);
```

I had have error:

> Error: The keyPress binding is not supported by the input element

Example in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dude_jsfiddle/byA75/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `kendo.data.binders.widget` namespace should be used when creating widget bindings. Widgets are created for elements that have their `role` data attribute set. You need `kendo.data.binders` only:

```
kendo.data.binders.keyPress = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
});
```

More info is available in the [custom binding](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/mvvm/bindings/custom) help topic.