# How add custom binding to DropDownList

Tags: kendo-ui

I have binding enterPress

```
// Custom keypress on ENTER event binding for input elements.
kendo.data.binders.enterPress = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function (element, bindings, options) {
        kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);
        var binding = this.bindings.enterPress;
        $(element).bind("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                binding.get();
            }
        });
    },
    refresh: function () { }
});
```

If I use it to DropDownList I have error:

> Uncaught Error: The enterPress binding is not supported by the
>   DropDownList widget

How to make enterpress for DropDownList ?

Answer (score 1):

Check my reply to your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709192/keypress-on-input-not-worked) question:

> The `kendo.data.binders.widget` namespace should be used when creating
>   **widget** bindings. Widgets are created for elements that have their role
>   data attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the keydown event of all DropDownList controls using the following code:

```
kendo.ui.ComboBox.fn._keydown = function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("key pressed!");
    }
};
```