# Keypress custom binding on input still not worked in kendo ui mvvm

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I think my question is similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709192/keypress-on-input-not-worked). However, event keypress on input text still not worked.

My Question here is how to add custom binding into input text box and trigger 'something' when pressing enter button.

Here is another [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546606/kendo-mvvm-and-binding-or-extending-custom-events) when the target is kendo widget; and it's working.

HTML code:

```
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" data-bind="keyPress: onKeyPress" />
    <div id="output"></div>
</div>
```

Java script code:

```
kendo.data.binders.keyPress = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
init: function (element, bindings, options) {
    kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);
    var binding = this.bindings.keyPress;
    $(element.input).bind("keypress", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            binding.get();
        }
    });
    },
    refresh: function () { }
});

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    onKeyPress: function () {
        $("#output").append("<div>keyPress</div>");
    }
});
kendo.bind($("#app"), viewModel);
```

Jsfiddle code:
http://jsfiddle.net/ikomangmahendra/4uL8Y/2/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was connected with the following line:

```
before:
$(element.input).bind("keypress", function (e) {

after:
$(element).bind("keypress", function (e) {
```

I should bind the event to the element, not to element.input.